# Split dataframe columns according to string pattern matching

Tags: r, dataframe, split

### Problem - Data Wrangling:

I want to fine adjust the note of a Multiple-Choice-Questions exam with 5 items on each question - A, B, C, D, E. I want to use coefficients on each possible item. For this I need to do some data wrangling:

### Input:

```
library(tibble)

(
  df <- tribble(
  ~id,   ~Q1,   ~Q2,   ~Q3, 
#|----|------|------|------|
    1,  "CDE",   "A",  "AD",
    2,  "CDE",  "AB",  "AD",
    3,   "DE",  "BC",  "AD")
)
```

### Expected output :

| id | Q1_A | Q1_B | Q1_C | Q1_D | Q1_E | Q2_A | Q2_B | Q2_C | Q2_D | Q2_E | Q3_A | Q3_B | Q3_C | Q3_D | Q3_E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very clever oneliners from other posters but hard to decypher.

This is a more readable solution imho:

```
ABCDE <- LETTERS[1:5]
one_col_to_five <- function(col) sapply(ABCDE,  grepl, col)
(proper_df <- do.call(cbind, lapply(df[, -1], one_col_to_five)))
(proper_df <- as.data.frame(cbind(df$id, proper_df)))

names(proper_df) <- c("id", paste(rep(names(df[-1]), 5), ABCDE, sep = "_"))
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use `mtabulate` by splitting

```
library(qdapTools)
cbind(df[1], do.call(cbind, lapply(df[-1],
       function(x) mtabulate(strsplit(x, "")))))
```

---

Or using `base R` with `table` after splitting each of the column values with `strsplit`, get the frequency count and then `cbind` the `list` elements

```
cbind(df[1], do.call(cbind, lapply(df[-1], function(x) {
       x1 <- strsplit(x, "")
 as.data.frame.matrix(table(data.frame(ind = rep(seq_along(x1), 
    lengths(x1)), val = factor(unlist(x1), levels = LETTERS[1:5]))))})))
```

-output

```
#  id Q1.A Q1.B Q1.C Q1.D Q1.E Q2.A Q2.B Q2.C Q2.D Q2.E Q3.A Q3.B Q3.C Q3.D Q3.E
#1  1    0    0    1    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    1    0
#2  2    0    0    1    1    1    1    1    0    0    0    1    0    0    1    0
#3  3    0    0    0    1    1    0    1    1    0    0    1    0    0    1    0
```

Answer (score 0):

Another base R option

```
cbind(
  df[1],
  `colnames<-`(
    do.call(
      cbind,
      lapply(
        df[-1],
        function(x) {
          t(sapply(
            strsplit(x, ""),
            function(v) table(factor(v, levels = LETTERS[1:5]))
          ))
        }
      )
    ),
    paste0(rep(names(df)[-1], each = 5), "_", LETTERS[1:5])
  )
)
```

which gives

```
  id Q1_A Q1_B Q1_C Q1_D Q1_E Q2_A Q2_B Q2_C Q2_D Q2_E Q3_A Q3_B Q3_C Q3_D Q3_E
1  1    0    0    1    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    1    0
2  2    0    0    1    1    1    1    1    0    0    0    1    0    0    1    0
3  3    0    0    0    1    1    0    1    1    0    0    1    0    0    1    0
```